# Design Suggestions for an Optocoupler Relay Module

Tags: mosfet, relay, power-electronics, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I have designed this module to operate with input voltages of 5V and 3.3V (common in most MCUs). Additionally, I have equipped it with an optocoupler to isolate the MCU from the power section of the circuit.

[image: Schematic]

I wanted to know if you have any design or optimization suggestions?

Comment: Why you need a two isolation? Opto and relay both. Opto waist at least 1mA of current(usually more) . Also driving IRF44 with 4.5v is at the edge of threshold(but should work).

Comment: There is no specification in which way you would like to see it improved. If it works as per your specs already then there is nothing to improve. Although that IRFZ can handle a lot more current than you need. Do you want your circuit cheaper, or being improved to be better than necessary? Do you need faster contact release time? Do you need an AC snubber to prevent contacts from welding?

Comment: Is K1 supposed to be a relay? I've never seen that symbol before, looks like a cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optocoupler fills no purpose, get rid of it. And as already noted by @Spehro, the MOSFET is completely overkill. It's rated for 49A(!).

The *only* components you need:

- The relay of whatever coil voltage that makes sense - not important.
- A simple SOT23 N-channel with decent V<sub>GS</sub> characteristics that can handle 3.3V logic. For example SSM3K339R.
- The flyback diode. 1N4148 will do fine.
- (optional) Two resistors for the gate, for example 10k series + 10k pull-down. 10k series will protect the MCU, pull down will keep the MOSFET stable while the MCU is booting.

Comment: This helps me a lot, very appreciate. I replaced the IRFZ44N with the SI2302 but cannot remove the Opto because i need the isolation from the power section.

Comment: @LuisJ.Mora What do you think the relay does then?

Comment: I use the relay because it is more suitable for controlling the high power load, while the optocoupler to provide electrical isolation, since my application is very sensitive to interference, also to ensure safety in the control system.

Comment: @LuisJ.Mora The only interference existing between the controller and the relay is literally the reverse EMF from the relay coil and you've already dealt with that. So there is nothing else that can "cause interference". EMC is science like everything else in electronics, it's not black magic. If you are paranoid, you can add some signal diodes from ground and to a V rail. They cost around a 10th of the optocoupler and are far more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I would substitute an inexpensive BJT or SOT23 logic-level MOSFET for that enormous TO220 power MOSFET (that isn’t logic level drive anyway). The relay is only 80mA.

R2 is unnecessary with a MOSFET.

Your LED current is on the high side >20mA for the best life from the opto with 5V input. I have not looked at the CTR margin, but you should allow a good worst case margin (low input voltage, low ambient temperature, marginal opto performance) to allow for aging,

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the IRFZ44N with the SI2302 and removed R2.